# Why does std::iter::Peekable::peek mutably borrow the self argument?

Tags: rust

I am struggling to understand why the `peek()` method is borrowing the self argument mutably.

The [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/struct.Peekable.html#method.peek) says:

> "Returns a reference to the next() value without advancing the iterator."

Since it is not advancing the iterator, what is the point behind borrowing the argument as mutable?

I looked at the implementation of `peek()` and noticed it is calling a `next()` method.

```
#[inline]
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
pub fn peek(&mut self) -> Option<&I::Item> {
    let iter = &mut self.iter;
    self.peeked.get_or_insert_with(|| iter.next()).as_ref()
}
```

Is it because of the use of the `next()` method, the `peek()` method is designed to borrow mutably or is there another semantic behind the `peek()` method that really requires the mutable borrow?

In other words, what is it that gets mutated when the `peek()` method is called?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you have already done, let's look at [its source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/core/iter/adapters/peekable.rs.html), which reveals a little about how it works internally:

```rust
pub struct Peekable<I: Iterator> {
    iter: I,
    /// Remember a peeked value, even if it was None.
    peeked: Option<Option<I::Item>>,
}
```

Together with its implementation for `next()`:

```rust
impl<I: Iterator> Iterator for Peekable<I> {
    // ...

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<I::Item> {
        match self.peeked.take() {
            Some(v) => v,
            None => self.iter.next(),
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

and it's implementation for `peek()`:

```rust
impl<I: Iterator> Peekable<I> {
    // ...

    pub fn peek(&mut self) -> Option<&I::Item> {
        let iter = &mut self.iter;
        self.peeked.get_or_insert_with(|| iter.next()).as_ref()
    }

    // ...
}
```

Peek **wraps** an existing iterator. And existing iterators are not peekable.

So what peek does, is:

- on `peek()`:

  - take the `next()` item from the wrapped iterator and store it in `self.peeked` (if `self.peeked` does not yet contain the next item already)
  - return a reference to the peeked item
- on `next()`:

  - see if we currently have a `self.peeked` item
  - if yes, return that one
  - if no, take the `next()` item from the underlaying iterator.

So as you already realized, the `peek()` action needs `&mut self` because it might have to generate the next peeked item by calling `next()` on the underlying iterator.

So here is the reason, if you look at it from a more abstract point of view: The next item might not even exist yet. So `peeking` might involve actually generating that next item, which is definitely a mutating action on the underlying iterator.

Not all iterators are over arrays/slices where the items already exist; an iterator might by anything that generates a number of items, including lazy generators that only create said items as they are asked for it.

Could they have implemented it differently?

Yes, there absolutely is the possibility to do it differently. They could have `next()`ed the underlying iterator during `new()`. Then, when someone calls `next()` on the `Peekable`, it could return the currently peeked value and query the next one right away. Then, peeking would have been a `&self` method.

Why they went that way is unclear, but most certainly to keep the iterator as lazy as possible. Lazy iterators are a good thing in most cases.

---

That said, here is a proof of concept how a prefetching peekable iterator could be implemented that doesn't require `&mut` for `peek()`:

```rust
pub struct PrefetchingPeekingIterator<I: Iterator> {
    iter: I,
    next_item: Option<I::Item>,
}

impl<I: Iterator> PrefetchingPeekingIterator<I> {
    fn new(mut iter: I) -> Self {
        let next_item = iter.next();
        Self { iter, next_item }
    }

    fn peek(&self) -> Option<&I::Item> {
        self.next_item.as_ref()
    }
}

impl<I: Iterator> Iterator for PrefetchingPeekingIterator<I> {
    type Item = I::Item;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        std::mem::replace(&mut self.next_item, self.iter.next())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut range = PrefetchingPeekingIterator::new(1..10);
    dbg!(range.next().unwrap());
    dbg!(range.peek().unwrap());
    dbg!(range.next().unwrap());
    dbg!(range.peek().unwrap());
    dbg!(range.next().unwrap());
    dbg!(range.peek().unwrap());
}
```

```
[src/main.rs:27] range.next().unwrap() = 1
[src/main.rs:28] range.peek().unwrap() = 2
[src/main.rs:29] range.next().unwrap() = 2
[src/main.rs:30] range.peek().unwrap() = 3
[src/main.rs:31] range.next().unwrap() = 3
[src/main.rs:32] range.peek().unwrap() = 4
```

Comment: Ahh now I see, the `take()` call in `next()` method is removing the peeked value so that when we can call `next()` again we get a new value.

Comment: @anilbey Added source code for an alternative implementation of a peekable iterator that doesn't require `&mut`. Maybe that helps your usecase.

Comment: and calling `peak()` is first calling `next()` that is removing the peaked value and then re-inserting the same value using `get_or_insert_with`, right?

Comment: `get_or_insert_with()` only calls `next()` if it doesn't contain a value yet. Note the `||` in front of it, making it a closure.

Comment: To keep `peek` non-mut they could also have used internal mutation, but then if they used `RefCell` it would not have been `Sync` and if they used `Mutex` you would be paying extra performance even if not needed.

Comment: Nice and detailed, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes as you noticed `Peekable::peek` might have to call `self.iter.next()` to get an element if its `self.peeked` doesn't already have something stored.
It then also has to store that value somewhere to not advance the `Peekable` iterator.
The underlying `Iterator` may very well get advanced by it.

Both advancing the underlying `Iterator` as well as storing the value in `self.peeked` require mutable access to `self`.